# Listing without "headers" for every directory

Tags: bash

is it possible to make a listing of every data in the root directory including the path but without every Directory in a new section? Something like this but without every a "header" on every directory"

ls -l $PWD/*

Comment: Please give an example of the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to see hidden files you can use

```
find $PWD -maxdepth 1 | xargs ls -ld
```

Or use `grep -v "${PWD}/\."` when you don't want them.

Comment: it bearly is the way i wanted it but is there a way to do this only for the root and not for every directory on the whole pc?

Comment: already found out thanks without you i probably couldn't do it

Comment: but can i sort it with the creation date and time?

Comment: Maybe something like `ls -lr $(find $PWD -maxdepth 1)` will help.

Answer (score 0):

pipe to awk to handle it.

```
 ls -l * | awk '$1!="total"'
```